# How to use patch.object() correctly

Tags: python

I'm trying to get my head around Mock and patch(), but I'm stuck on a somewhat simple example. Say I have the following function in `main.py`, which tests if it's a weekday or not.

```
from datetime import datetime

def is_weekday():
    today = datetime.today()
    return (0 <= today.weekday() < 5)
```

I want to run my test with two possible outcomes: either `False` if I mock Saturday or Sunday or `True` if it's a weekday. Now, I'm clearly not mocking anyting when calling `main.is_weekday` so my test currently fails as it's the weekend. How can I fix that?

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
import pytest
import main

def test_weekday():
    datetime = Mock()
    tuesday = datetime(year=2019, month=1, day=1)
    datetime.today.return_value = tuesday
    with patch.object(datetime, "main.is_weekday", tuesday) as mock_method:
        expected = True
        actual = main.is_weekday() # how do I mock datetime.today()?
        assert actual == expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The essential problem is that you're not patching `datetime` in your `main` module. The first argument to `patch.object` is the thing you want to patch, and since you're passing in your `datetime` Mock object, that doesn't do you any good.

I would restructure your test like this:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
from datetime import datetime
from mockito import when, ANY

import main


def test_weekday():
    testdate = datetime(year=2019, month=1, day=1)
    with patch("main.datetime", wraps=datetime) as mock_datetime:
        mock_datetime.today.return_value = testdate
        assert main.is_weekday()


def test_weekend():
    testdate = datetime(year=2019, month=1, day=5)
    with patch("main.datetime", wraps=datetime) as mock_datetime:
        mock_datetime.today.return_value = testdate
        assert not main.is_weekday()
```

Here, we're replacing `main.datetime` with a mock object, and then configuring it such that calling `datetime.today()` in the `main` module will return a specific date.

Then we test that the code works as expected for both weekdays and
weekends.